# Cannot compare NSString with Swift's static let string

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a ViewController subclass which segues off into multiple different other views (using a single ViewController type). I have put identifiers on the segues in the Storyboard and I want to compare them at runtime so I can pass data to them, like so:

```
class MyListViewController : UITableViewController {

        static let segueNameFoo : String = "segueFoo"
        static let segueNameBar : String = "segueBar"

        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            super.prepareForSegue( segue, sender: sender )

            if segue.identifier == segueNameFoo {
                let vc : MyDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MyDetailViewController
                vc.someData = "foo"
            } else if segue.identifier == segueNameBar {
                let vc : MyDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MyDetailViewController
                vc.someData = "bar"
            }
        }
}
```

Problem is, Xcode 7.3 gives me these errors:

> Static member `segueNameFoo` cannot be used on instance of type `MyListViewController`
>   Static member `segueNameBar` cannot be used on instance of type `MyListViewController`

When I change it to just `let segueNameFoo : String = "segueFoo"` it builds and runs fine.

I don't understand why it's complaining - `segue.identifier` is an `NSString*` and Swift supports `==` comparisons between them. My use of `static let` is so that `segueNameFoo` isn't allocated for every instance of `MyListViewController`. What's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you use like this it means segueNameFoo is instance member

```
segue.identifier == segueNameFoo
```

is equal to

```
segue.identifier == self.segueNameFoo
```

So you should use  `MyListViewController.segueNameFoo`. so it will be look as class member(Similarly to static)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unrelated to `String` vs `NSString`.

You have defined *type properties*, these are referenced as `MyListViewController.segueNameFoo` etc.

Answer (score 0):

in swift 2 you can use this:

```
let str = "string"
let nsstr:NSString = "string"
if nsstr.containsString(str){
print(true)
}else{
print(false)
}
```